# Intellisense for external javascript files in VS2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2008 SP1 to do intellisense for external javascript files, as described [here by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx), but it's not working.

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with several javascript files in the Scripts directory. All of the scripts are included on a master page. Intellisense is enabled, but it only gives me the basic javascript language stuff-- nothing defined in my scripts. I have tried adding `/// <reference path="Global.js" />` comments to the top of the files, with no luck. It doesn't work in script blocks in the master page either. Is there something else I need to do to get this working?

**Edit:** I'm not using jquery. From Scott's article it didn't sound like I needed any -vsdoc.js files; is this incorrect? If so, where do these files come from for my own external scripts?

Comment: Bo you dun need the vsdoc on your own script. If you have the include inside your Site.Master. You still need the reference on your asp pages or in you scrpt page where you want the intellisense is enabled. What do you see into the status bar , after rebooting visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download the hotfix KB958502:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=14883&wa=wsignin1.0

Be sure to have the file -vsdoc.js in the same directory as you main js script. And the must have the same name. For exemple jquery.1.3.2.js and jquery.1.3.2-vsdoc.js

And i had to reload all the visual studio when i've installed the hotfix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need a -vsdoc.js file? I'm not using jquery, I want intellisense for my other script files.
Installed the hotfix & nothing changed =(
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave all the debug scripts in the Scripts folder?  e.g. jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js?